# Run an additional script after django server is started

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I have a simple Django API that runs via docker-compose and I want to run a script `bot.py` after the server starts. How I can do this using docker?

My `Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.8
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

And `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
    web:
        build: .
        command: bash -c 'python3 network/manage.py makemigrations &&
                          python3 network/manage.py migrate &&
                          python3 network/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000'
        volumes: 
            - .:/code
        ports: 
            - "8000:8000"
```

I tried to add `CMD [ "python", "./bot_new/bot.py" ]` but it doesn't work actually

Comment: Can you run it in a separate container?  You can use `command:` in the `docker-compose.yml` to override the Dockerfile's `CMD` with an alternate command.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your script in a Django command following [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-management-commands/) tutorial and then in your main app execute the command after the app is ready like:

```
from django.core.management import call_command
from django import apps

class MyAppConfig(apps.AppConfig):
name = 'myapp'

def ready(self):
    call_command('bot')
```